# Cucumber, How to check if parent has a certain class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I am using cucumber with rails, and I'm checking if the parent of an element has a certain class. I found this code, but it doesn't work. I'm using Capybara by the way. Thanks in advance!

```
Then the element "([^"]*)" with parent "([^"]*)" should have class "([^"]*)" do |element_id,parent,css_class|
  response.should have_selector "#{parent} .#{css_class}" do |matches|
    matches.should have_selector element_id
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, this isn't really the way you should be testing with cucumber. Cucumber is for testing behaviour, not checking the DOM - though of course it can be used in that way.

If you're really wanting to write something like this, you could make that much simpler:

```
Then /^the element "([^"]*)" with parent "([^"]*)" should have class "([^"]*)"$/ do |element_id,parent,css_class|
  page.should have_css("#{parent}.#{css_class} #{element_id}")
end
```

This sucks on many levels, though. Not only are you checking the DOM directly from the step, which makes for very unreadable features, but you're mixing passing in element names, class names and element IDs - each with a slightly different style... In this step, element can be any type of selector whereas parent and css_class are much more fixed - they must always 'fit' into the selector string or it won't find anything.

I haven't really explained that very well, but in a nutshell, you should consider what you're actually trying to test and think whether it can be renamed to something more useful and re-usable. Would you ever be able to re-use that step without looking at it's implementation to figure out what goes where?

Also, with more expressive naming, the test instantly becomes more useful later down the line. For example, the step `Then I should see the current list is active` is much more readable and expressive than `Then the element "li.active" with parent "ul" should have class "active-list"`. Be specific in the step definition implementation, not your features!

Have a read of this blog post - http://elabs.se/blog/15-you-re-cuking-it-wrong - it should give you a good idea of how to write better steps.